# When Add new purchase I want to update Quantity in another table

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have tblPurchase table and tblProductStock table. When I add new record to the tblPurchase table, automatically takes that value to the tblProduct Stock table. Its Fine. But When I add new product with same ItemCode Quantity will change to 25 + 15 = 40. Its also fine. But Still first record is not deleted. Therefor In my totalStock table shows 40 + 15 = 55. That output is wrong. I want to get only 40.
This Total Stock Details is shows wrong output 40 + 15 = 55. I need 25 + 15 = 40

I want to If Itemcode is already existing in table I wanna update Quantity. if no have any item with new record i want insert that data to tblproductstock table.

[image: This is both the tables]

I want to update that table not insert every new record. and sum quantity according to the itemcode.

[image: This is my stored procedure for Automatically inserting data to tblProduct Stock table when we add new purchase.]

Please help me to recover this problem .
Thank you !

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Edit your question so the code is *text*.  That makes it much easier for someone else to help.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this scenario:

```
SELECT MAX(ItemName) ItemName,
   ItemCode,
   SUM(Quantity) Quantity
INTO #tmp
FROM tblPurchase
GROUP BY itemCode;

UPDATE tblProductStock
SET Quantity=#tmp.Quantity
FROM #tmp WHERE tblProductStock.ItemCode=#tmp.ItemCode

INSERT INTO tblProductStock
    (
        ItemName,
        ItemCode,
        Quantity
    )
SELECT  ItemName, ItemCode, Quantity FROM #tmp WHERE ItemCode NOT IN (SELECT ItemCode FROM tblProductStock)

DROP TABLE #tmp;
```

I hope it helped.

Comment: How to write Update quary. Can you please tell me

Comment: When I use this code data is insert to the tblPurchase table. but Not tblProductStoct table.Can you please tell me Why is that ? thank you

Comment: When I add new record to the tblPurchase table not insert data to the tblProduct Stock. Why is that

Comment: @SandanuwanDharmarathna Are you sure? It's clear and ``Insert into tblProductStock``  will insert into tblProductStock. Can you share query completely.

Comment: How can I send my code to you @Saeed. I am New to here

Comment: Can you please give me your email address. i will send that to your mail

Comment: @SandanuwanDharmarathna Please update your question with new code.

Comment: Ok I will do it

Comment: I uploaded new question. According to your code what is #tmp. which table name is come to that place

Comment: @SandanuwanDharmarathna It is a temp table and  will create in tempdb and will be destroyed by drop table. Can you comment your new question link.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65776251/update-tblproductstock-table-when-insert-new-record-to-tblpurchase-table?noredirect=1#comment116296594_65776251

Comment: @SandanuwanDharmarathna the answer is correct. How and when you call stored procedure?

Comment: Can you understand my problem. I have tables called tblPurchase And tblProductStock. When I add new record I want to send same data to the tblProductStock table also. And next time when I add same Product with same ItemCode I dont want to duplicate tblProductStock table.I want to update only Quantity Column. If ItemCode is not in tblProductStock table I want to add is as new record.

Comment: Ok I will send Stored Procedure

Comment: In sql show one error in your code. (ItemCode is Ambiguous) After  FROM #tmp WHERE ItemCode=#tmp.ItemCode

Comment: I edited my code. can you see that. its my stored procedure

Comment: @ Saeed Esmaeelinejad Its working as expected. I don't want to drop my tblPurchase table. I want to keep all record in tblPurchase table

Comment: I said drop #tmp not purchase table

Comment: after adding new record all purchase table record deleted. and new record insert. I want to avoid that. if i comment DROP TABLE #tmp; this line I think its ok?? but not confirm

Comment: I want to add those products and stock permanent not temp.

Comment: @ Saeed Esmaeelinejad Which time that tables drop. before its work. but now table is not drop

Comment: @seeed Esmaeelinejad  without create temp how can I keep both tables value permanent. How can I change this stored procedure

Comment: I rolled back the last edit because it totally changed the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question well, maybe something like MySQL's "on duplicate key update" or PostgreSQL's "on conflict do update" could work for you here.