# Update tblProductStock table when Insert New record to tblPurchase table

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPassPurchaseDataToProductStock]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(ItemName) ItemName, ItemCode, SUM(Quantity) Quantity
    INTO #tmp
    FROM tblPurchase
    GROUP BY itemCode;

    UPDATE tblProductStock
    SET Quantity = #tmp.Quantity
    FROM #tmp 
    WHERE ItemCode = #tmp.ItemCode

    INSERT INTO tblProductStock (ItemName, ItemCode, Quantity)
        SELECT ItemName, ItemCode, Quantity 
        FROM #tmp 
        WHERE ItemCode NOT IN (SELECT ItemCode FROM tblProductStock)

    DROP TABLE #tmp;
END
```

Comment: If you have a question, you should be clear.  After you clarify the question, add an appropriate database tag.

Comment: look for Sql triggers.

Comment: Or indexed views

Answer (score 1):

I think that SQL Server Trigger Can help you to solve this problem.
A trigger is a special type of stored procedure that automatically runs when an event occurs in the database server.

```
   CREATE TRIGGER <TriggerName>  
   ON ProductStock  
   AFTER INSERT | UPDATE 
   AS  { sql_statement }
```