# How can I keep tblPurchase and tblProductStock table without drop. (I need keep both table and value permanent without drop)

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

How to change this stored procedure without drop tblPurchase and tblProductStock.
When I run my program with this stored procedure after adding new record table and data will be drop. I want to keep all table and data protected. please help me to resolve that.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65774309/13338320

Comment: What are you trying to do with that stored procedure? And what do you not want to drop? The temp table? So put it in a standard table.

Comment: Looks like you might want to try [Indexed Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Questions should be self contained. If there is information in a related question then include it in this question and cite the source.

Comment: @Charlieface Can you please tell me how to do that

Comment: @Charlieface do you know rewrite this code . i dont want to drop both tables.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that you are trying to store a rolled up `SUM` of `Purchase` within the `ProductTable`?

Comment: @Charlieface I want to keep Sum of Quantity in my tblProductStock table.but because of this stored procedure query all data suddenly delete.I want keep both the tables and table values

Answer (score 1):

### Indexed View

---

An entirely new solution based on [Indexed Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15) is possible.

An Indexed View is a view which has a clustered index on it, and the data is actually stored on disk.

As I understand it, you are trying to keep a sum of purchases per product item stored in `tblProduct`. I have assumed that `ItemCode` is the PK of tblProduct and that `ItemName` is also defined there (We cannot use `MAX` in an indexed view). So we can define a view like this:

```sql
CREATE VIEW dbo.vwTotalPurchases
WITH SCHEMABINDING  -- must be schema bound, we cannot change underlying columns after creation
AS
SELECT
   ItemCode,
   SUM(Quantity) QuantityPurchased,
   COUNT_BIG(*) CountPurchases  -- if we group, must have count also, so that rows can be maintained
FROM dbo.tblPurchase  -- must use two-part names
GROUP BY itemCode;
GO
```

We can then create a clustered index on it to persist it on disk. SQL Server will maintain the index whenever an update to the base table happens. If there are no more rows in the grouping (identified by count being 0), then the row is deleted:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_vwTotalPurchases ON dbo.vwTotalPurchases (ItemCode);
GO
```

Now if we want to query it, we can left join this view onto `tblProducts` (left join because there may be no purchases):

```sql
SELECT
    p.ItemCode,
    p.ItemName,
    ISNULL(tp.QuantityPurchased, 0) QuantityPurchased,
    ISNULL(tp.CountPurchases, 0) CountPurchases
FROM tblProducts p
LEFT JOIN vwTotalPurchases tp WITH (NOEXPAND) ON tp.ItemCode = p.ItemCode;
```

We can define this as a view also (not an indexed one, but a standard view) so that the definition is usable anywhere.

---

### Note on `NOEXPAND`:

If you are not on SQL Server Enterprise or Developer Edition, you must use the hint `WITH (NOEXPAND)` to force it to use the index, otherwise it will query the base `tblPurchase` instead. And even in those editions, it is best to use `NOEXPAND`.

See [this article](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/12/sql-performance/noexpand-hints) by Paul White on this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But when I execute this command line (CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ON dbo.vwTotalPurchases (ItemCode);
GO) it shows this error (Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'). Can you please tell me how to resolve this error. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry forgot to give it a name, see edit `CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_vwTotalPurchases ON dbo.vwTotalPurchases (ItemCode);`

Comment: Thats fine. I have some questions. Can you plese give me your email address. I want to solve this problem. I tried to solve this problem 4 days. still not finished. please help me

Comment: Before I pass data from tblPurchase to tblProductStock table using stored procedure. But  in that time records and table deleted. Because of temp table. But Now I want to Pass data to the tblProductStock table using another way. Can you please tell me how to  pass data to tblProductStock table from tblPurchase table without duplicating record

Comment: Use triggers? But what do you need to pass that my answer doesn't help for?

Comment: I want to passe ItemName, ItemCode,QuantityPurchased,CountPurchases to tblProductStock table. but with your codes tblPurchar, View and Index work well. But not send data to the tblProductStock

Comment: can you please send me your mail. I need to finish this problem.