# Getting an error "Msg 512, Level 16" after insert using a trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, triggers

I need to create a trigger to update the `Total` column after each new addition of damage.

The Total must be increased with the cost of this damage, so I have this error :

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TotalDmg, Line 4
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

My script :

```
create database carsLoan
use carsLoan

create table Loan
(
    idL int primary key, 
    Total float
)

insert into Loan 
values (1, 300), (2, 200), (3, 400)

create table Damage
(
    idD int primary key, 
    idL int references Loan, 
    description varchar(100), 
    Cost float
)

insert into Damage 
values (1, 1, 'Damage1', 70), (2, 2, 'Damage2', 90), (3, 3, 'Damage3', 80)

alter trigger TotalDmg 
on Damage 
after insert 
as
begin
    declare @cost float
    set @cost = (select Cost from Damage 
                 where idD = (select idD from inserted))

    declare @total float
    set @total = (select Total from Loan 
                  where idL = (select idL from inserted))

    update Loan 
    set Total = @total + @cost 
    where idL = (select idL from inserted)
end
```

Comment: Your trigger is flawed; it assumes an `INSERT` only every affects 1 row; that is simply not true.

Comment: @ Larnu So how to fix this?

Comment: Also `float` is a poor choice of a data type what what I assume is a monetary value.

Comment: Do YOU have every error number memorized? Neither does anyone else. Post the complete error message.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers)

Comment: @SMor Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TotalDmg, Line 4
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Brent Ozar says: [The Silent Bug I find in Most Triggers:](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/)

You are not taking into account `inserted` having multiple rows, or even none at all.

```sql
alter trigger TotalDmg on Damage after insert as
-- the whole batch is the trigger, no need for BEGIN/END

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;   -- best practice
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted))
    RETURN;

update l
set Total = l.Total + i.cost
from Loan l
join (
    select i.idL, sum(i.Cost) cost
    from inserted i
    group by i.idL
) i on i.idL = l.idL;

GO
```

If you make an `UPDATE` trigger, please also compare the `inserted` and `deleted` tables with this code:

```sql
join (
    select i.idL, sum(i.Cost) cost
    from (
        select i.idL, i.Cost from inserted i
        except
        select d.idL, d.Cost from deleted d
    ) i
    group by i.idL
) i on i.idL = l.idL
```

---

### See also [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65781667/14868997) for a much better solution involving Indexed Views

Comment: `XACT_ABORT` is naturally on for triggers - although I guess it doesn't hurt to add it again. "inserted having multiple rows" or none! :)

Comment: @DaleK another error message : Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure TotalDmg, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'.

Comment: @Charlieface an error message : Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure TotalDmg, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'.

Comment: And personally I prefer a begin/end for my triggers - seems clearer to me ;)

Comment: @DaleK yes it's entire code in my quetion

Comment: @DaleK Oh !! I can't belive it ! it works now ! I swear it doesn't before realy I dont know why ? I'm so sorry guys, thanks a lot Chalie

Comment: @DaleK Thank you Man ;)

Comment: @DaleK Interesting. That does seem to be true about XACT_ABORT, but have you got any docs to back it up? btw did you look at my other post?

Comment: Yip, I did see your other post. Interesting. Docs to back up what?

Comment: @Charlieface [docs to back up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) " OFF is the default setting in a T-SQL statement, while ON is the default setting in a trigger."