# View to sum over products

Tags: sql-server, database-design, view

I have three tables for a mock/fake database I am creating to learn SQL

```
Purchases
PK    Purchase_ID
FK    Creditcard_ID
      Order_Date

Products
PK    Product_ID
      Product
      Description
      Cost

Purchases_Products
PK    Purchases_Products_ID
FK    Purchase_ID
FK    Product_ID
      Quantity
      Review
```

I want to add a View column under Purchases, Total_Cost, that computes this value:

```
Summation[Product_ID]_(Purchases_Products.Quantity * Products.Cost)
```

Which sums over all products belonging to a single Purchase_ID. This will require a join. How may I accomplish this?

(edit: While learning how to use a join in a constraint for a Junction Table to prevent null values in parent tables was a great read and something I may want to implement, I still do not understand my question any better sadly.)

Comment: This sounds like a column that should be defined in a `VIEW`, not a computed column. Computed columns that require data from other rows, or tables, must use user defined scalar functions, and can result in your queries being significantly slowly that if you were to use a simple aggregate function in the `SELECT`.

Comment: @Charlieface It is a little advanced for me, so sadly I do not see the link aside from how to implement a join. I will look into how to define a column through a view.

Comment: Sorry wrong link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65778999/how-can-i-keep-tblpurchase-and-tblproductstock-table-without-drop-i-need-keep/65781667#65781667

Comment: @Charlieface Both posts are also advanced for me, but offer some good hints. Maybe this question was too big for me to ask at my level and I need to build up to this question slowly.

Comment: There is the other way: a user-defined function in a computed column. I strongly advise against it for performance reasons though. @Larnu did you see my linked answer