# Add computed columns to a table counting records from another table by associated id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add 2 computed columns to my table that counts records in another by Id

Last column to get a % if possible

Tasks is the table with the 3 columns the id for this is

```
TaskId     Guid
```

TaskDetails is the table I want to count

- TaskDetails has a TaskId Guid

We will select the columns

```
Completed, Total, CompPerc
```

Total column just needs to count the records associated with the Task.
Completed column needs to count the records associated with the Task Where IsComplete == true.

CompPerc column needs to get a percentage of the associated records where IsComplete == true and Total. I am not sure how to do this because you cannot compute off of a computed column. Maybe there is another way?

I tried doing it this way for the 1 column but it doesn't seem to work.

```
INSERT INTO [Tasks] (Completed)
    SELECT COUNT(TaskDetails.TaskDetailId) 
    FROM TaskDetails 
    WHERE TaskId = Tasks.TaskId
```

Comment: It looks like you actually want a view here (possibly with CTEs so you can calculate in stages), not computed columns. Those should not be used to compute values from data other than constants and the current row (even though you can hack around it with functions); views are not so restricted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I keep tblPurchase and tblProductStock table without drop. (I need keep both table and value permanent without drop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65778999/how-can-i-keep-tblpurchase-and-tblproductstock-table-without-drop-i-need-keep)

Comment: I have used a lot of views. I do agree that it would make the computing easier and it is just for viewing purposes anyway. I have done easy computed columns where I multiply a money column by number. I have a SQL programmer but he was busy doing something else so i thought i would see what this turned up.

Comment: From a performance perspective you absolutely don't want a computed column referencing other tables. To do that requires wrapping the calculation inside a user-defined function which cannot get inlined nor optimized by query planner, so it will get executed once for every row in the referencing table. As @JeroenMostert suggested, you are much better off creating a view that adds the computations because at least that code can be inlined and optimized - even removed from the plan entirely if the caller doesn't ask for it.