# After Update Trigger to Maintain Badge Count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I was wondering how I could accomplish something with a trigger on a table I have created?

I have the following tables:
ClientAccount
ClientActivity

In ClientAccount I have an attribute that is a count of the number of ClientActivity records that a Client has. I use that count as a Badge on a tab.

Whenever a new activity is created the following trigger fires off:

```
SELECT ALL

USE [officemgt]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[RecountInsertedClientActivities] 
   ON  [dbo].[CLIENTACTIVITY]
   AFTER INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE CLIENTACCOUNT
    SET Count_ClientActivitiesAsClient=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ClientActivity WHERE ClientActivity.parent_Client_RID=CLIENTACCOUNT.ID)
    FROM inserted
    LEFT JOIN CLIENTACCOUNT ON CLIENTACCOUNT.ID=inserted.parent_Client_RID

END
```

I then have a similar trigger that fires off if a ClientActivity record is Deleted.

These two triggers work just fine.

The issue is that sometimes an activity may be changed from one client to another. So, I would need to update the counts for both the old client so it is reduced and then update the count for the new client the activity was assigned to.

How can I do that?

Comment: Create an after update trigger and do pretty much what you are doing now?

Comment: Check reference here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15.  Just so you understand completely, the "deleted" table inside a trigger does not exist only within a DELETE trigger - it also exists within an UPDATE trigger, and in that instance it will hold the pre-update values (hence Dale's answer works because the client ID in the "deleted" table is the value before it was changed)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65778999/how-can-i-keep-tblpurchase-and-tblproductstock-table-without-drop-i-need-keep/65781667#65781667 which shows a much better solution based on indexed views for a similar problem, no triggers needed

Comment: Why bother? A view can be defined to "virtually" do this without the complication of trigger code and the view will always be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a **single** trigger that handles insert, update and delete as follows:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[RecountInsertedClientActivities] 
   ON  [dbo].[CLIENTACTIVITY]
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE CA SET
        Count_ClientActivitiesAsClient = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.ClientActivity CV WHERE CV.parent_Client_RID = CA.ID)
    FROM dbo.CLIENTACCOUNT CA
    WHERE CA.ID in (SELECT I.parent_Client_RID FROM INSERTED I UNION ALL SELECT D.parent_Client_RID FROM DELETED D);
END;
```

Comment: Thanks Dale, I actually wondered if it was possible to do all of the in one trigger. I like that solution the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `deleted` table. `inserted` contains all the new records, `deleted` contains all the all records in your update/delete trigger:

```
  UPDATE CLIENTACCOUNT
    SET Count_ClientActivitiesAsClient=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ClientActivity WHERE ClientActivity.parent_Client_RID=CLIENTACCOUNT.ID)
    FROM inserted
    LEFT JOIN CLIENTACCOUNT ON CLIENTACCOUNT.ID=inserted.parent_Client_RID


  UPDATE CLIENTACCOUNT
    SET Count_ClientActivitiesAsClient=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ClientActivity WHERE ClientActivity.parent_Client_RID=CLIENTACCOUNT.ID)
    FROM deleted
    LEFT JOIN CLIENTACCOUNT ON CLIENTACCOUNT.ID=deleted.parent_Client_RID
```

Comment: You probably need to mention that an 'update' trigger needs to be created.

Comment: The actual table names within the trigger are "deleted" and "inserted"